# Apache2 config to redirect wildcard secure domains

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I own secure site https://example.com.

I want to redirect all URLs http://whatever.example.com and https://whatever.example.com to the correct URL https://example.com.

This is my apache2 config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName x.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect 301 / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    Redirect 301 / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine with http://whatever.example.com: Apache handles the request and redirects to the correct URL. However, there is a problem with https://whatever.example.com. At least on Chrome, I first get warning that this site is not secure (obviously, there is no ssl certificate for whatever.example.com), and only when I force the browser to load that page, only I get redirected.

So, is there a better redirect than what I am using right now? One that would not confuse user with strange browser warnings.

Comment: You must add those subdomains to your TLS certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need a wildcard certificate for the domain, or a SAN certificate for the subdomains that you plan to redirect.